# How do I set state from within a fetch in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have the following component class:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import './login.css';

export default class Login extends Component {

    handleSubmit = (e) => {

        var myRes = null;

        fetch(
            "/exist/apps/my-app/modules/who-am-i.xq?user=emh&password=emh",
            {
            }
        )
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(
            (result) => {
                myRes = {
                    error: null,
                    loaded: true,
                    user: result
                };
            },
            // Note: it's important to handle errors here
            // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
            // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
            (error) => {
                myRes = {
                    error: error,
                    loaded: true,
                    user: {}
                };
            }
          );
        this.setState(myRes);
    }

    render() {
        return (
      <div className="auth-wrapper">
        <div className="auth-inner">
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h3>Sign In</h3>
.
.
.
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">Submit</Button>
            </Form>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I have searched for the answer, but what I got was in `(result) => {this.setState({error: null, loaded: true, user: result})}`.  Unfortunately the `this` is undefined within the fetch.

I want to in the result and error to set the value in state.  Unfortunately the this is not defined within the fetch result.  How do I set the state in `Login` from within the fetch?

Comment: Seems like you are setting the state without awaiting the resolution of the promise, so you will always set state to `null`

Comment: @thedude is correct.  You're setting state outside the promise callback, which means it's probably running before the promise does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're calling `setState` too soon. You need to call it only when your promise has settled. The easiest way to do that is with a subsequent `then`, see `***` comments:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    // *** No `let myRes` here
    fetch(
         "/exist/apps/my-app/modules/who-am-i.xq?user=emh&password=emh",
         {
         }
     )
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then(
         (result) => {
             // *** Transform the resolution value slightly
             return {
                 error: null,
                 loaded: true,
                 user: result
             };
         },
         // Note: it's important to handle errors here
         // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
         // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
         (error) => {
             // *** Turn rejection into resolution by returning
             // a replacement for `myRes`.
             return {
                 error: error,
                 loaded: true,
                 user: {}
             };
         }
       )
       .then(myRes => {
         // *** You always end up here because both fulfillment and rejecction
         // result in an object that's used to fulfill the promise
         // created by the first call to `then`
         this.setState(myRes);
       })
       // *** Still use a final handler to catch errors from
       // fulfillment handlers
       .catch(error => {
         // Handle/report error
       });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all fetch should always be async
second put `const that = this;` in the top of the handler and then you can do setState like this:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
        const self = this
        var myRes = null;

        fetch(
            "/exist/apps/my-app/modules/who-am-i.xq?user=emh&password=emh",
            {
            }
        )
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(
           result => {
                self.setState({error: null, loaded: true, user: result})
                myRes = {
                    error: null,
                    loaded: true,
                    user: result
                };
            },
            // Note: it's important to handle errors here
            // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
            // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
            (error) => {
                myRes = {
                    error: error,
                    loaded: true,
                    user: {}
                };
            }
          );
    }
```

and advise you to create a file for the fetch like this:

```
 const nameYouDecided = async () -> {
    await fetch("/exist/apps/my-app/modules/who-am-i.xq?user=emh&password=emh" )
          .then((response) => response.json())
    }
```

and then when you call it in your code it is shorter
In addition if you have a couple of get request you should do the following
in different file like get.js

```
    const get = async (url) => (
        await fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => json
            )
    );
const nameYouDecided = get("/exist/apps/my-app/modules/who-am-i.xq?user=emh&password=emh")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the state inside of .then() fetch function.

Fetch need time to fetch urls, setstate doesnt wait this time so it set a Promise. To turn around this, you need to put your setState inside a .then, the setState line will only be executed when your fetch done the job

```
fetch(
  "/exist/apps/my-app/modules/who-am-i.xq?user=emh&password=emh",
  {
  }
)
.then((response) => response.json())
.then(
  (result) => {
      return {
          error: null,
          loaded: true,
          user: result
      };
  },

  (error) => {
      return {
          error: error,
          loaded: true,
          user: {}
      };
  }
).then(myRes => {
  this.setState(myRes); 
});
}
```